# is it good to keep all static data which may change only once an year in database or filesytem?

Tags: mysql, memory, database-design, normalization

While Designing a Mysql database, I am keeping all the static data in the xml files rather then in database tables. On the Run time application will create a singleton and get all the static data in memory...
static data is Like below

- List of countries in the world
- Number of states in India

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that this over-complicates the application.  Using a database as a data store for *all* common data in an application is a simplification, not a complication.  It is easy enough to load data from a single table into memory, so there isn't much effect on performance or application code complexity.

Storing data in XML files requires either replicating those files wherever the application is running.  Or, it requires having a common file system for accessing the files.  In either case, why have duplication or additional access control issues?  If you are storing data in a database, you have already solved these problems.

You may also want this data to be combined with other data in the application.  For instance, the list of countries could provide a `CountryId` column, referenced by an address.

I would argue that storing the data in the database is the right way to go.

Comment: +1: Particularly, I'd echo the point that placing data outside of the database makes it inaccessible to SQL for efficient bulk data processing.